# Animated element replacement

Tags: javascript, css

please tell me how to make the container smoothly increase in height and decrease depending on the height of the child element
My code work without animation

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  document.getElementById("page1").style = "display:none";
  document.getElementById("page2").style = "display:block";
}, 5000);

setTimeout(() => {
  document.getElementById("page1").style = "display:none";
  document.getElementById("page2").style = "display:block";
}, 15000);
```

```css
.container {
  width: 50vmin;
  background: green;
  transition: all 5s ease;
  display: block;
}

#page1 {
  width: 25vmin;
  height: 50vmin;
  background: red;
  display: block;
}

#page2 {
  width: 25vmin;
  height: 10vmin;
  background: black;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="page1"></div>
  <div id="page2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'll be happy to see examples)) Video-example that i wanna make https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KSKdRLGptgDbYgvbyWw4uKraKYtKXDKw/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Do you want to use javascript or css if fine!

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you apply a transition, apply the transition animation to the element you want to watch and make it smooth animation.

**Also note:** Instead of updating `display none and block`, as you want to watch the height animation, update the style `height` style.

**Here is a working example:**

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  document.getElementById("page1").style = "height:20vmin";
  document.getElementById("page2").style = "height:20vmin";
}, 5000);
```

```css
.container {
  width: 50vmin;
  background: green;
  display: block;
}

#page1 {
  width: 25vmin;
  height: 50vmin;
  background: red;
  display: block;
  transition: all 5s ease;
}

#page2 {
  width: 25vmin;
  height: 10vmin;
  background: black;
  display: none;
  transition: all 5s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="page1"></div>
  <div id="page2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but is it possible that the size of the parent changes depending on the size of the child. I just don't know the height of the child component, it depends on the number of nested components...

Comment: @alexanne, it's possible. You can get it by using targettedElement.offsetHeight or targettedElement.clientHeight